# Resize Image with responsive layout

Tags: css

Can someone help me figure out why my logo image isn't resizing according the the browser size?

----------------CSS---------------------

```
body {
       height: 100%;
       background-color:#333;
}
#logo {
      max-width: 100%;
}
img {
     border: 0;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;

}
#header-bg {
    background-image: url("header-bg.png");
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

----------------HTML-------------------

```
 <body>
    <div id="header-bg">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" /> 
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is, you have given `max-width`, which might be less than the original `width`. So giving `width` will solve your issue.

```
img {
     border: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

Other than this, everything is right.

---

If you feel that your image is not soooo big, that it occupies the whole width of the screen, give a smaller width to the parent, say `25%`. And to the image a `width` of `100%`. So the parent adjusts for sure according to the width of the screen, so is your image. `:)`

Comment: when I set width to 100%, it expands the logo on the entire window.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle for you to show what @Praveen Kumar explained: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/4h2xU/1/

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Dude, that is seriously a biggest image with a largest size! :P It is taking more than a minute to load in 12 mbps connection! `:o`

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Then lemme wait and check it out. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry, I did not realize the image was so large!  Just found something cool from google!

Comment: Add display:block in img css